# How to convert timestamp from datatype string to datatype timestamp in Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, timestamp

in my HIVE table_one CREATEDDATE is datatype = STRING and I want to convert CREATEDATE to datatype timestamp in timezone 'Europe/Berlin'.

```
Table_one Field CREATEDDATE (STRING) UTC+0: "2022-07-13T09:30:19.000+0000"
```

This is my spark sql function where I load CREATEDDATE from table_one:

```
, to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CREATEDDATE , "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss Z")),'CET') AS CREATEDDATE
```

But after insert into table_two with Field CREATEDDATE = TIMESTAMP, the field is still null.

What's wrong with my function? Wrong format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `T` with a space and youre good to go.
Your code should be

```
select to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(replace(createdate,'T',' '))),'CET') time_in_CET
```

Example below -

```
select  to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( replace('2022-07-13T09:30:19.000+0000 Z','T',' '))),'CET')
```

[image]